# Sass refactoring variable as selector

Tags: variables, sass, refactoring

I'd like to refactor this code if possible, I didn't find something to figure it out :

```
$javascript: rgb(238, 218, 103); 
$php: rgb(119,125,176); 
$ruby: rgb(197, 25, 17);

.isjavascript {
    color: $javascript;
}

.isphp {
    color: $php;
}

.isruby {
    color: $ruby;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Nothing, I'm just trying to refactor this to get something like
.is#{$color}{ color: $color; } but here I want color to be a reference to an other variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use a [map](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps).

```sass
$languages-color: (
  'javascript': rgb(238, 218, 103),
  'php': rgb(119,125,176),
  'ruby': rgb(197, 25, 17)
);

@each $label, $color in $languages-color {
  .is#{$label} {
    color: $color;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ty ! Exactly what I was looking for !